# SharePoint Hosted App Code behaves different

Tags: sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

This code is working if i dont use it in a app. But in a app its not working. The app is sharepoint hosted, and the list is on the same domain as the app.

```
context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    var currentUser = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('popupNews');
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
    this.items = list.getItems(query);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'items' of undefined

Comment: Obviously, `this` does not refer to what you think it refers to. If you wish to provide the entire code, we may be able to help.

Comment: Do you have two lists with the same name? One on the SharePoint site hosting the app, and one on the App site?  You say it works when not in an app, and that the list is on the same domain as the app, but apps are deployed on a different domain than the SharePoint host site, and the cross domain library is required to query lists on the host site.  So the only way you can successfully perform this outside an app, and for the list to be on the same domain as the app is if you have two lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following method to get listitems:

```
function getListItems(listName, siteurl, success, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a SharePoint Hosted app, the app pages are deployed to a separate domain.  In order to access content on the SharePoint site, you must use the cross-domain library.

The cross-domain library is a client-side alternative in the form a of a JavaScript file (SP.RequestExecutor.js) that is hosted in the SharePoint site that can be referenced to in your app.  You can use it with either REST or JSOM.

To use the cross-domain library with REST:

```
function execCrossDomainRequest() {
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/title?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: successHandler,
        error: erroHandler
    });
}
```

To use the cross-domain library with JSOM:

```
function execCrossDomainRequest() {
    context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
    factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
    context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
    appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);

    var web = appContextSite.get_web();
    context.load(web);
}
```

In order to use the cross-domain library, you must reference the SP.RequestExecutor.js file:

```
var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";
$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function() {
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function() {
        $.getScript(scriptbase = "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);
    });
});
```

You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927%28v=office.15%29.aspx).  There are examples, as well as links to working code examples using both REST and JSOM.